# Failing to authenticate user on login with passport and bcrypt

Tags: node.js, authentication, bcrypt

So I am trying to create a signup/login logic for my website using passport and bcrypt-nodejs for password hashing. I am successful at registering a user, but then on login I always get into the 'false' branch for password authentication and am getting my console message for 'Wrong Password' Here is my login passport code:

```
passport.use('user-local-login', new LocalStrategy({
// by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
usernameField : 'email',
passwordField : 'password',
passReqToCallback : true   
},
function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

// find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
// we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
User.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
  // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
  if (err)
  return done(err);

  // if no user is found, return the message
  if (!user) {
    console.log('No user found.');
    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
  }

  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, res) {
    if (err)
    throw err;
    if(!res) {
      console.log('Ooops!. Wrong Pass!');
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });
});
}));
```

And here is my signup logic

```
passport.use('user-local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField : 'email',
passwordField: 'password',
passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
  function (req, email, password, done) {
// asynch
// User.findOne will not fire unless data is sent back
process.nextTick(function() {
  User.findOne({'email' : email}, function (err, user) {
    if(err)
    return done(err);
    if(user) {
      console.log('That email is already taken');
      return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
    } else {
      // checks for password and repeat_password match
      if (password != req.body.repeat_password) {
        console.log('Passwords do not match.');
        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Passwords do not match.'));
      }

      var newUser = new User();
      newUser.email = email;
      bcrypt.hash(password, null, null, function(err,hash){
        if (err)
        throw err;
        else {
          newUser.password = hash;
        }
      });

      newUser.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
        throw err;
        return done(null, newUser);
      });
      console.log('New user was created: ' + email);
    }
  });
});
}));
```